# failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400 using Arduino

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, arduino

I'm trying to set up a Node.js local server in order to collect data from an Arduino connected by serial port (using USB).

I'm using socket.io in order to connect server and client, reading data using Node.js and then send it to the client webpage.

Last month the code was working perfectly, now (after no changes at all), i try to run it and i get this error.

I used some testing logs and the connection seems to work ( '1 connection' is being printed).

This is the Node.js code:

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');
var io = require('socket.io');
const SerialPort = require('serialport');
const parsers = SerialPort.parsers;


const port = new SerialPort('COM3', () => {
console.log('Port Opened');
});
const parser = new parsers.Readline({
delimiter: '\n'

});

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response){
var path = url.parse(request.url).pathname;

switch(path){
    case '/':
        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        response.write('hello world');
        response.end();
        break;
    case '/socket.html':
        fs.readFile(__dirname + path, function(error, data){
            if (error){
                response.writeHead(404);
                response.write("opps this doesn't exist - 404");
                response.end();
            }
            else{
                response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
                response.write(data, "utf8");
                response.end();
            }
        });
        break;
    default:
        response.writeHead(404);
        response.write("opps this doesn't exist - 404");
        response.end();
        break;
}
});

server.listen(5000);
port.pipe(parser);

io.listen(server);

var listener = io.listen(server);

listener.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
console.log('1 connection');

function ReadSerialData(data){
    console.log(data);
    console.log('Connection');
    //do stuff here
    //socket.emit('message', 'connection successuf');

    socket.emit('message', {'message': data})
}

parser.on('data', ReadSerialData);
});
```

And this is my `socket.html` code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      var socket = io.connect();
      socket.on('message', function(data){
      console.log(data.message);
      });
    </script>
    <div>Testing page! </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried everything but i can't get out of this

Comment: You're calling `io.listen(server);` twice. Also, the client not being able to load the socket.io script is *definitely* a problem (as should be clear from the error messages in the browser console).

Comment: So basically could be a problem of the source code not available anymore? I didn't change anything to the code in the last month, now i'm running it again and i have this problem.
Accessing to '/socket.io/socket.io.js' using a browser leads me to an error 404.

Comment: Removing the extra io.listen(server), solved the error, but i'm not able to access the serial data. The function 'ReadSerialData' is never called, i think there are some problems with the parser.on function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the double `io.listen(server);` solved the error.

The `error 404` given by accessing `/socket.io/socket.io.js` is not a problem, once the server is correctly running it will disappear.

The problem with the data was in the parser: the delimiter was `\n` but in the Arduino code was printed a `\r` as new line.